# Disable CTRL-ALT-DEL in android

Tags: android, keyboard-events

I have an android device with physical keyboard, i am trying to override keyboard events. I was successful with commenting the keylayout files. But the combination  CTRL-ALT-DEL reboots the device. Is there a way to override this key combination ?

Comment: Ask the device manufacturer.

Comment: That CTRL-ALT-DEL reboots the device is a good thing. No need to change this behaviour.

Comment: You can probably alter this behavior in the kernel - it may actually be implemented there anyway.  If not, if it goes directly to a supervisory microcontroller or something like that, you are probably out of luck.

Comment: thanks everyone I would dig more your inputs !

Answer (score 0):

echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/ctrl-alt-del

Or edit init.xxx.rc

write /proc/sys/kernel/ctrl-alt-del 0